# Home partition emergency mode

Tags: mount, fstab, home

I recently mount my home partition(my home partition is separated from root) of the Endeavour-OS from my Garuda-OS, that cause me to boot into emergency mode in my Endeavour(that should have mountpoint to my home partition).

How should i proceed with this? Is the only way is to create user and add it to home dir with complete wipe the partition?

i get this from running command "lsblk":

```
> lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    10M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   587M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0  62.5G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0 167.6G  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0   7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
```

the sda4 is the separate home partition.

and from command "blkid" :

```
>blkid
/dev/sda4: UUID="0c89ef83-da81-442c-892f-71b3052b571a" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="48b27dc3-d86c-3d4c-9b1e-d78021cd98a0"
/dev/sda2: LABEL_FATBOOT="BOOT" LABEL="BOOT" UUID="755B-69B5" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="f1e54924-905f-cf4c-bec1-10ab3c250c0f"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="swap" UUID="52300be2-937a-418d-bad9-5242dc99145e" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4c30f20f-b803-244e-ac6d-278b140c5aad"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="root" UUID="d3013930-9d00-4308-8151-554debf4459e" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4 PARTUUID="1ea51fa9-c68a-4149-b550-ae6a5ea06087"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="grub" UUID="af50eeae-7c6e-4b27-be02-4ee679a30c31" BLOCK_SIZE="1024" TYPE="ext4 PARTUUID="d369f82d-e25c-9448-8149-519b41cb3db8"
```

this is my /etc/fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=755B-69B5                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults,noatime 0 2
UUID=d3013930-9d00-4308-8151-554debf4459e /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID=0c89ef83-da81-442c-892f-71b3052b571a /home          ext4    defaults,noatime 0 2
UUID=52300be2-937a-418d-bad9-5242dc99145e swap           swap    defaults   0 0
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

**Edit: **
I might have figured out the problem,
after i use command `mount -a` it returns nothing. Then, i try `lsblk` again and the mountpoints of `/home` partition refer sda4:

```
> lslbk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    10M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   587M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0  62.5G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0 167.6G  0 part /home
└─sda5   8:5    0   7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
```

But after i do `startx` since i'm using i3WM, it didn't get me to my display

I did `fsck -l` and get these problem :

```
[root@ifhonce /]# fsck -l
fsck from util-linux 2.38.1
fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'UUID=d3013930-9d00-4308-8151-554debf4459e'
```

Comment: Did you try `fsck` to correct any file system errors that might have prevented mounting at boot?  Are you replacing Endeavour with Garuda?

Comment: I try fsck before with `fsck -y /dev/sda3` but i don't think its correct. I don't replace Endeavour with Garuda, it's just they're in different drive

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Most likely the filesystem corruption was caused by improper shut down, like a crash or lost power.  If it happens again, especially if frequently, then you should look at other causes, like hardware failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is SOLVED now

Before i use `fsck -y /dev/sda3` on my `/` dir, instead it I should `fsck` my home partition using `fsck -f -y /dev/sda4`

Thanks to this, I have little knowledge about how mountpoints work and fstab in my machine. I'm trying to get the right tags and words in google so hard before I know that i get the boot problem before with `Dependency failed for /home/$USER`.

source : [Manjaro Forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/dependency-failed-for-home/69639)

Comment: WARNING: If you use `fsck` to "fix" a mounted filesystem you will almost certainly end up corrupting that file system irretrievably.

Comment: May vary with file system because each one has its own implementation, but `fsck` should complain and abort if the drive is mounted rw, even with the `-f` flag.